# Drop-shadow not working properly on iOS Safari

Tags: html, css, dropshadow

I have added drop shadows to labels for checkboxs so that when they are checked the drop shadow appears. They work perfectly on chrome however when I tried them on safari on both my mac and iPhone the drop shadows are not appearing. I have tried using the -webkit-filter CSS but this has not had any effect.

I have included both the HTML and CSS below.

```
<li>
<input type="checkbox" id="dairy" name="lifestyle" value="dairy-">
<label for="dairy">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0433/2958/5306/files/Cheese_Icon.png?v=1611093331" class="choose--contents--img" alt="">
<p>Dairy</p>
</label>
</li>


label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #5E7735;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 117.5px;
  height: 140px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

:checked + label {
  filter: drop-shadow(6px 6px 0 #5E7735);
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(6px 6px 0 #5E7735);
  -moz-filter:  drop-shadow(6px 6px 0 #5E7735);
  -ms-filter:  drop-shadow(6px 6px 0 #5E7735);
  -o-filter: drop-shadow(6px 6px 0 #5E7735);
  transition: filter 0.1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: filter 0.1s ease-in;
}
```

They should look like this

[image: Example of them from chrome]

But they look like this (the shadow is cut off)

[image: Example from Safari]

Comment: This is a horrible problem with css for Safari, both on an iOS device and on a Mac. I'm not sure there is a good solution to this problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was playing with this I think one solution could be to use a box shadow, and apply border-radius that is using vw, for proportionality.

Something like this:

```css
.class {
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 0 #5E7735;
    border-radius: 5vw; /* Or whatever fits the corners of the image used) */
}
```

It's a workaround but hopefully it can help someone out there!